# Onmouseover OnMouseout javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote a script which changes the source of an image upon mouse over the image,
at first it worked, but after adding a second image which uses the same code both stopped working.

The issue I am experiencing is that the image does not change on mouse over as it should. It looks as if the image is not found – however I am really sure the images' sources point to the right path.

I have asked for other opinions as well and I cannot see what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate your help or any input on this.

Below is the code I am using.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var images= new Array();
      images[0] = "Benjamin/Untitled-3.png";
      images[1] = "Benjamin/Untitled-4.png";
      images[2] = "Benjamin/Update.png";
      images[3] = "Benjamin/Update2.png";

      function Change()
      {
        document.getElementById("image").src = images[1];
      }

      function GoBack()
      {
        document.getElementById("image").src = images[0];
      }

      function GobackAgain()
      { 
        document.GetElementById("Update").src = images[2];
      }

      function ChangeAgain()
      {
        document.getElementById("Update").src = images[3];
      }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      body
      {
        background-color:#1c1a1a;
      }
    </style>

    <div align="center">
      <img src="Untitled-2.png" width="325" height="191">
    </div>

  </head>

  <body>
    <img onmouseover="Change()" 
         onmouseout="GoBack()" 
         id="image" 
         STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35%; LEFT:10%; WIDTH:204px; HEIGHT:278px" 
         src="Untitled-3.png">

    <img onmouseover="ChangeAgain()" 
         onmouseout="GoBackAgain()" 
         id="Update" 
         STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:35%; LEFT:50%; WIDTH:204px; HEIGHT:278px" 
         src="Update.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `GobackAgain` contains an error: `GetElementById` doesn't exist, use `getElementById`

Comment: Oh sorry , dident spot your anwser! yes i changed that still does not work :/ ty for your fast anwser!

Comment: No problem, see my full answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `GobackAgain` to `GoBackAgain` and replace `GetElementById` with `getElementById`.

Comment: Do you maybe know an alternative way to do it maybe ?

Comment: Yes , you are right my mistake , thanks for all your help really apriciate it!=)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one problems:

```
function GobackAgain()
{ 
    document.GetElementById("Update").src = images[2];
}
```

You have `GetElementById` when it should be `getElementById`

Comment: Fixed that , but still the same happens !:/ btw thanks for your fast anwser!=)